# Magento 1.9 - Recently viewed products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, checkout

I am using the the Recently viewed products reporting on my basket page.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Is it possible to exclude items that are contained in the cart from this report?

This is the full code for that report:

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
    <div class="block-title">
        <h2 style="margin-top:1.2rem;"><?php echo $this->__('Have you considered?') ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul id="recently-viewed-items" class="recently-products-list">
        <?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <div class="product">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(300) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-details">
                        <div class="product-info-top">
                        <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                        <div class="sku"><?php echo $_item->getSku(); ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                        <div class="actions">
                        <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Basket')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Basket') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php else : ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code instead of yours:

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
    <?php $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote(); ?>
    <?php $cartProductIds = array(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($cart->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): ?>
        <?php $cartProductIds[] = $item->getProduct()->getId(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <div class="block block-list block-viewed">
        <div class="block-title">
            <h2 style="margin-top:1.2rem;"><?php echo $this->__('Have you considered?') ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <ul id="recently-viewed-items" class="recently-products-list">
            <?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?>
                <?php if(!in_array($_item->getEntityId(), $cartProductIds)): ?>
                    <li class="item">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-image">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(300) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-details">
                                <div class="product-info-top">
                                <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                                <div class="sku"><?php echo $_item->getSku(); ?></div>
                                </div>
                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                                <div class="actions">
                                <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Basket')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Basket') ?></span></span></button>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Happy to help! When you reach 15 then upvote please.